# Not able to drop foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby on rails 2.3.9. The rake db:migrate passed successfully. However when I run rake db:migrate:redo to test the down part I get error message. I am using mysql with Innodb.

```
class AddConstraints < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-EOS
      ALTER TABLE venues
      ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (city_id)
        REFERENCES cities (id)
        ON DELETE restrict
        ON UPDATE cascade
    EOS
  end

  def self.down
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-EOS
      ALTER TABLE venues DROP FOREIGN KEY (city_id)
    EOS
  end
end
```

The error message I am getting is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near '(city_id)' at line 1:       
ALTER TABLE venues DROP FOREIGN KEY (city_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should omit the parentheses after `FOREIGN KEY`. Second, you must tell mysql the name of the fk constraint you want to drop, not the name of the column affected by that constraint. If you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE venues`, you can find out the name of the constraint - probably something like  `venues_ibfk_1` or similar. Use this name for the `ALTER TABLE` statement, e.g. `ALTER TABLE venues DROP FOREIGN KEY venues_ibfk_1`.

Comment: I see. However that means the nake of foreign key will be different for different people. It means there is no clean way to fix this problem using ruby rails. unless I dynamically find the correct foreign_key. Is there a way to tell mysql to create foreign key with a specific name or is it totally upto mysql?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "different name for different people". Anyway, you can choose the name of the foreign key when you create it, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html (or the respective pages for your version of MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove the parentheses from the statement? A quick google showed statements without parentheses being used in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: removing parantheses lead to a different error. Mysql::Error: Error on rename of './eii_development/venues' to './eii_development/#sql2-85-101' (errno: 152):       ALTER TABLE venues DROP FOREIGN KEY city_id

Comment: It's quite late, but it's probably worth a note that I had the same error. Then it turned out, that MySQL excpects foreign key name case sensitively.